# How to handle inconsistent wait issues for angular applications using protractor jasmine

Tags: angular, protractor

I am working for angular based application with protractor and jasmin . While executing e2e tests, the test scripts are failing inconsistently. So we used ignore.synchronized = true to avoid the inconsistency. But it is taking nearly one to two minutes to execute the next step in the test scripts. Could you please help us on this to reduce the time duration taken to click next element.

Comment: it seems clicks are waiting for something, if no waiters are called explicitly. try to use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`. With this call you're less likely to misstype when trying to ignore synchonization

Comment: I tried browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); aswell, in that case it is executing so fast and tests are failng.Is there any other way to handle waits??

Comment: @sindhukommoju tests are failing with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`  because now your application now has no waits at all between actions. I would not recommend disabling this feature without understanding why the application takes long to load or is producing the failures (as waiting for the page to stabilize is one of Protractors most useful features). Can you post a little more about the kind of failures you are seeing inconsistently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

To handle wait issues:

use `browser.waitforAngularEnabled(false)` after getting your base url. Then you can use expected waits which makes the protractor wait until that expectation is completed.

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions for more details